# Reshape structure into a matrix without for loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a structure (data) which consist of 322 cells a 296(features)*2000(timepoints). I want a matrix per timepoint which consists of trials^features^timepoints (322 *296*2000). What I am currently doing and what also works fine is using a for-loop:

```
for k=1:size(data.trial{1,1},2)
    for i= 1:length(data.trialinfo)
        between=data.trial{1,i}';
        data(i,:,k)=between(k,:);
    end
end
```

Can anyone think of a faster way to do that? Because it takes ages as the matrix increases.

Thanks!

Carlos

Comment: have you tried the **reshape** function?

Comment: Also look at [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html?s_tid=doc_ta)

Comment: Oh yes--I should have mentioned that but I have tried both of them in many variations and it never gives me the same results ; for instance: reshape(cell2mat(data.trial)',[322,296,2000]);

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data2 = permute(reshape([data.trial{:}],296,2000,322),[3,1,2]);
```

The issue with `reshape` is that it thinks in columns, so you need to `permute` afterwords (ie. 3D transpose), since that's how you set up the output variable in your loop. I used concatenation instead of `cell2mat` for speed.

I assumed this worked as sample data:

```
for ii= 1:322
    data.trial{1,ii} = rand(296,2000);
end
```